# only use the filename for move

Tags: find, mv, basename

I have to move some files from one folder to another, criteria set by a find and grep. When I try to move the files it breaks.

The actual move it's trying is `mv /somefolder/export//somefolder/storage/testfileOLD.txt`

What I expected was `mv /somefolder/storage/testfileOLD.txt /somefolder/export/testfileOLD.txt`

The command I'm using:

```
find /somefolder/storage/ -type f -name "*OLD*" -newermt '2019-05-1' ! -newermt '2019-06-7' -exec grep -qiF 'closed' {} \; -exec mv {} /somefolder/export/{} \;
```

I already tried with `-exec basename {}`, this gives me the right result, but when I modify the mv to

`-exec echo {} /somefolder/export/$(basename {}) \;`

to check if it works it still gives me the `/somefolder/export//somefolder/storage/testfileOLD.txt`.

Comment: Do you need the `{}` in destination for `mv`? It should work fine if you just leave it as `-exec mv {} /somefolder/export/ \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(basename {})` will fail (better: just be an empty string). The subshell invoked here does not expand `{}` to the filename as this is specific to find and not exported into the subshell your command creates.

You can test this by running

```
find -exec echo "this will be empty:" $(basename '{}') \;
```

I suggest you write a small script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv "$1" /somefolder/export/"$( basename ${1})"
```

and run it in your `find` command:

```
find /dir/ <specs> -exec grep -qiF 'closed' '{}' \; -exec bash script.sh '{}' \;
```

---

AFAIK the behaviour of forwarding `'{}'` to subshells depends on your `find`-version.

Comment: Updated - I had focused on how to circumvent `'{}'` for more complex commands in `find`

Comment: thanks, I used your idea, but used the inline sh -c for this to work
`-exec sh -c 'mv {} /somefolder/export/$(basename "$1")' sh {}` as this will not add extra scripts on the server (even one that can be deleted directly afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the original structure below directory `/somefolder/somedir`, you could use `rsync` instead of `mv`.

Test setup:

```
/somefolder/storage/testfileOLD.txt
/somefolder/storage/subdir/fileOLD.txt
```

Expected result after move:

```
/somefolder/export/testfileOLD.txt
/somefolder/export/subdir/fileOLD.txt
```

The commands:

```
# first, create a file list of relative paths (some arguments removed for simplicity)
$ find /somefolder/storage -type f -name "*OLD*" -printf '%P\n' > /tmp/filelist

# cat to illustrate its content
$ cat /tmp/filelist
subdir/fileOLD.txt
testfileOLD.txt

# then rsync using `--remove-source-files` to move the files 
$ rsync -av --remove-source-files --files-from=/tmp/filelist /somefolder/storage /somefolder/export
```